# XLSX File uploaded through HTTP is corrupted. Content-Length changes

Tags: c#, excel, http, asp.net-web-api, content-length

I've been pulling my hair out as I cannot determine what is causing this problem.

So basically, I have an MVC app that uploads an xlsx file to a remote REST app via dropzone.js

This is the dropzone. It works perfectly. I omitted the rest of the code

```
dropzone.dropzoneConfig = {
        'options': {
            'url': 'http://remotehost:9090/api/path/to/upload',
            'headers': { 'authorization-apikey': '7CF5EBE7-79D8-4B33-8619-6802DCB783B7' },
            'maxFiles': 1,
            'maxFilesize': 500,
```

Using Fiddler to track my post. It is being sent as a `multipart/form-data` with a `Content-Length:10359`

[image]

The Problem is when it reaches the controller, the `Content-Length` suddenly becomes `15878`. And this makes it a corrupted file.

This is the controller. **BTW, I created a webapp just to test this method, and it does save the file successfully, not corrupted. EXCEPT for this main app that I am working on**

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> LoadFile()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        var provider = new CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(@"C:\Users\Desktop\testPath\filetoupload");

        try
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // Holds the response body

            // Read the form data and return an async task.
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            // This illustrates how to get the form data.
            foreach (var key in provider.FormData.AllKeys)
            {
                foreach (var val in provider.FormData.GetValues(key))
                {
                    sb.Append(string.Format("{0}: {1}\n", key, val));
                }
            }

            // This illustrates how to get the file names for uploaded files.
            foreach (var file in provider.FileData)
            {
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file.LocalFileName);
                sb.Append(string.Format("Uploaded file: {0} ({1} bytes)\n", fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.Length));
            }
            return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new StringContent(sb.ToString())
            };
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
        }
      
    }

public class CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider : MultipartFormDataStreamProvider
{
    public CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(string path) : base(path) { }

    public override string GetLocalFileName(HttpContentHeaders headers)
    {
        return headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
    }
}
```

When the XLSX file gets saved in that path provided above, it becomes corrupted and cannot be opened.

This is the returned data
[image]

I'm trying to understand what could be interfering with the http content when the file gets posted. Any ideas on how to debug this?

Thanks All,

Comment: What Content-Encoding are you setting in the body part for the file?  It looks like it's trying to decompress the file.

Comment: hi @Adrien Im not sure how to post the image in comment, but I debugged it and the Request.Content.Headers' Content-Encoding is nothing. `Content-Encoding = {}` . Essentially, I'm sending it through postman

Comment: Hi, there's Content-Encoding in the main headers of the request, but with a multi=part resource body, there are also Content-Type and potentially Content-Encoding headers in each body part as well - I think you'd need to use wireshark to see what this is being set to.